# Setting the Search Scope for Sharepoint Site Collection

Tags: search, sharepoint-2007

This is really strange.  I have 2 SP Web Applications.  One at **Port 80** and one at **Port 83**.

They are both **TeamSites** with the **Publishing Feature Activated**.  Both have a search box at the top right that allows me to specify the search scope.

The one at Port 80 allows me to select:

**This Site: Home**

**All Sites**

**People**

The one at Port 83 allows me to select:

**This Site: Intranet**

For both sites, i looked at:

**http://share2003/_layouts/viewscopes.aspx?mode=site**

**http://share2003:83/_layouts/viewscopes.aspx?mode=site and**

The settings are identical.  I will like to enable the rest of the search scopes for the web application at **Port 83**.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, where some of the site collections in my farm (1 WFE, 1 DB) contained all of the correct scopes ({This Site: , [This List: ], All Sites, People}), but others were missing "All Sites" and "People".

The site collections which were missing these Scopes also did NOT have the "Advanced Search" link to the right of the search box.

On all of the site collections where these scopes were available (and where the Advanced Search link was available), there was a sub-site (aka web) named something like "Search", and that sub-site was specified in the Site Collection settings -> Search Settings as the Search Center to use to show richer results (the first radio button option).

So on one of my site collections which was missing Scopes, I created a Search Center sub-site and set it as the custom search center (Site Collection settings -> Search Settings). After that, all scopes were available and "Advanced Search" is now shown.

Thanks to http://insidesharepoint.blogspot.com/2007/06/and-now-another-word-form-our.html , which helped put me on the right path.